# Smarty foreach loop and file_exist

Tags: php, foreach, smarty, php-extension, file-exists

I'm using the [Smarty php template engine](http://www.smarty.net/), and I'm trying to verify the existence of .jpg images with an `$id_attribute` name:

```
{foreach from=$product.colors key='id_attribute' item='color'}
    {if file_exists($img_col_dir|cat:$id_attribute|cat:'.jpg')} 
        yes 
    {else} 
        no 
    {/if}
```

The `$img_col_dir` is "http://www.domain.com/img/co/" and `$id_attribute` is a number. Many files exists in .jpg format, but the whole loop doesn't find anything, returning "no". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't check for existance of a file on a url,

```
http://www.domain.com/img/co/myfile.jpg
```

only on your local drive

```
c:\myfolder\myimages\myfile.jpg
```

also, you should do this logic in your php file, not in your smarty template.

Check if the file exists then pass through a smarty variable image_exists for each image.